# NSDocument display name of page with WebKit

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I'm trying to get WebKit to display the page title of the currently opened document window, which includes a WebView. The document won't display after I run the app.

I'm using Document.m and windowNibName to achieve this, but I'm sure what I'm doing is wrong. I think it might be with both the NSStrings, which I can't have. Though if I don't have them I can't return the Document title... (WebKit/WebKit.h is imported)

```
   - (NSString)windowNibName:(WebView *)sender didReceiveTitle:(NSString *)title forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    // Report feedback only for the main frame.
    if (frame == [sender mainFrame]){
        [[sender window] setTitle:title];
    }
    return @"Document";
}
```

Comment: Objective-C methods can't be nested like this.  (You have the definition of `-webView:didReceiveTitle:forFrame:` inside the definition of `-windowNibName`.  In addition, the return type of `-windowNibName` is `NSString *` whereas here nothing is returned.

Comment: HA! I'm so stupid, you're right! Could I basically nest               - (NSString *)windowNibName:(WebView *)  and return("+webView+"); ?

Comment: @Pxlc: Even if concatenating random objects with strings were supported in Cocoa, the `description` of a WebView probably isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You've implemented a method named `windowNibName:didReceiveTitle:forFrame:`, but nothing sends such a message (unless *you* are, but if you are, you left that code out).

The correct method name is [`webView:didReceiveTitle:forFrame:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView%3adidReceiveTitle%3aforFrame%3a). Assuming you only have one web view in the window and only one window in the document, and assuming that the document is the web view's delegate, you can simply [set the document's display name](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000008-SW54) from there.

If you have something more complex going on, with multiple web views per window and/or multiple windows per document, then you'll need to ask the web view for [its window](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/window), the window for [its window controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/windowController), and the window controller for [its document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/document), and then set the document's display name as above.

Also, `windowNibName` has nothing to do with setting the document's title to the web page's title. The web view probably hasn't even started to load a page yet, if it even has a URL to load at all. That's why you need to be the web view's delegate and respond to that delegate message.